# Setting Docker environment variables in Python cronjob

Tags: python, docker, cron

I've seen multiple questions on SO regarding my issue, but none of the solutions seem to work. I have a Docker container that runs a python script cronjob, at the moment I want it to run every minute. For some reason, it's not able to capture the environment variables.

My environment variables are set in a .env file. I have a docker compose file that reads the .env file into the cron container. To keep the length down, I won't post the docker compose or .env file.

This is my Dockerfile for the cron container, `cronpy` is what defines the cronjob:

```
FROM python:3.9.0
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN apt-get update &&\
    apt-get install -y libldap2-dev\
                       libsasl2-dev\
                       xmlsec1\
                       cron &&\
    pip install --upgrade --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org pip

RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code

COPY requirements.txt /code/
RUN pip install --upgrade --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org -r requirements.txt

COPY . /code/
COPY ./cronpy /etc/cron.d/cronpy

# Apply cron job
RUN crontab /etc/cron.d/cronpy

ENTRYPOINT ["/code/config/cron.sh"]
```

In my entrypoint script, I create a new script `cron_env.sh` with all of the environment variables I need:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set +e
set +x

env > cron_config

rm -f cron_env.sh

while read -r assignment; do
  echo "export ${assignment}" >> cron_env.sh
done < cron_config

chmod 755 cron_env.sh
rm -f cron_config

cron -f
```

Then, in my cronpy file I source the variables before running the command:

```
* * * * * root . /code/cron_env.sh; /usr/local/bin/python /code/manage.py capture_usage_metrics --type all > /proc/1/fd/1 2>&1
```

I'm still getting errors that the env variables aren't set. The `cron_env.sh` file is getting created fine.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue. One of the environment variables had special characters and was causing the `cron_env.sh` script to fail.